# Who cursed the Aztec gold coins?

Tags: character, pirates-of-the-caribbean

In conversation between him and Elizabeth, Captain Barbossa says these words,

> You don't know what this is, do you?
> It's a pirate medallion. This is Aztec gold. One of 882 identical pieces they delivered in a stone chest to Cortes himself. Blood money paid to stem the slaughter he wreaked upon them with his armies.
> But the greed of Cortes was insatiable. So, the heathen gods placed upon the gold a terrible curse. Any mortal that removes but a single piece from that stone chest shall be punished for eternity.

But

> Pintel (with Ragetti):
>
> Never sat well with Bootstrap, what we did to Jack Sparrow. The mutiny and all. He said it wasn't right with the Code. That's why he sent off a piece of the treasure to you, as it were. He said we deserved to be cursed...and remain cursed.

Who actually cursed the coins? Bootstrap or the heathen gods?

If it's bootstrap, how did he do it? he was just a mortal human back then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Heathen Gods.

Your quotes provide all the necessary information.

> So, the heathen gods placed upon the gold a terrible curse.

Bootstrap Bill only claimed they deserved to be cursed, he never actually cursed anything. In fact, by then, [he was already cursed as well](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/74665/32199).

> He said we deserved to be cursed...and remain cursed.

Comment: then how come they needed bootstrap's blood to lift the curse if he just claimed they need to be cursed?

Comment: The [link](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74652/why-is-turners-blood-necessary-to-break-the-aztec-gold-curse) I posted is actually the answer to that exact question! :D

Comment: @Vishwa I may be wrong here, but IIRC, they needed the blood from all of the involved on taking the Aztec coins. I presume all of the others had already given their own.

Comment: @Vishwa I just found this [answer in Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-was-Bootstrap-Bill-Turners-blood-necessary-to-lift-the-curse) that explains basically what I just said.